# Infinite loop when using value to call function to get data from REST Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, data-binding

I'm pretty new in the world of angular 2 & nodejs.

Currently I created a service that allows me to make a query through NodeJs that brings information from MySQL.

On that information I want to use a value that allows me to call a function that brings me the name associated with that id to be able to show it.

The idea is to find the name of the company associated with that ID and that is hosted in another table in the database.

When I make the call from the template, I can connect to the REST API but it starts an infinite loop that blocks my browser memory.

What would be the correct way to make this call and get this information.

**customers.service.ts**

```
export class customerService {
  private serviceUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/customers';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getCustomers(): Observable<CustomerList[]> {
    return this.http.get<CustomerList[]>(this.serviceUrl)
  }
  getCustomer(id): Observable<CustomerList[]> {
    return this.http.get<CustomerList[]>(this.serviceUrl+'/'+id)
  }
}
```

**view-budget.component.ts**

```
  getCustomerName(_id) {
    console.log('ID C:', _id);
    this.customerService.getCustomer(_id).subscribe(datos => {
      return this.getCustomer = datos;
    })
  }
```

**view-budget.component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let budget of viewbudget" id="{{budget.id}}">
    <h2>{{ budget.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</h2>
    <p *ngFor="let customer of getCustomerName()">{{(customer.name)}}</p>
    <p>Fecha Inicio: {{ budget.startdate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="price">$ {{budget.statusid}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It'd help to know the data model (especially the relationships), your problem might have a better solution in the back-end depending on that .
But the problem comes from calling  `getCustomerName()` in the template, and without an argument.
The flow should be like : get the data in `ngOnInit` -> put it in a variable -> show that variable in the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While It is indeed possible to solve the issue from the frontend, I think what you're trying to achieve here is more efficiently done with an **SQL join** on the back end. Then have the data you need **with** the company name ready for visualization from another API endpoint.

Once you have that, add a new method to your service, call it from the component's `ngOnInit`, store the result in the component, and vizualize it with :

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let budget of viewbudget" id="{{budget.id}}">
    <h2>{{ budget.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</h2>
    <p *ngFor="let customer of budget.customers">{{(customer.name)}}</p>
    <p>Fecha Inicio: {{ budget.startdate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="price">$ {{budget.statusid}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If there are many companies per budget,

or :

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let budget of viewbudget" id="{{budget.id}}">
    <h2>{{ budget.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</h2>
    <p>{{(budget.customer.name)}}</p>
    <p>Fecha Inicio: {{ budget.startdate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="price">$ {{budget.statusid}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If there's only one company (depending on your data models)

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to call functions from the template. Each time change detection runs, the function will be called again, which can cause errors like you're seeing.

Instead, create an `ngOnInit` function, and call it within there:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getCustomerName();
}
```

And amend your template to use the `getCustomer` variable you've created:

```
<p *ngFor="let customer of getCustomer">{{(customer.name)}}</p>
```

This way, the API call will only be made once (when the component is initialised)

Comment: An SQL joint is better suited for this kind of work, and then have the backend serve the data ready for visualization. Depending on the relationship between budgets and customers

Comment: @MohammedIlyassNASR This has nothing to do with SQL joins? I'm simply suggesting that the function call should be made from the ts code, and not called from the template

Comment: While I do agree it is indeed a solution, having `n` `budget` rows and a many to many relationship between those two entities would mean calling the API a huge amount of times every time the component loads thus increasing the strain on the server, unnecessarily. This can be leveraged by having better API endpoints. OP clearly stated that with every `budget` row there is a company id, and that he wants to look for the name corresponding to the id. this is not frontend work.

Answer (score 0):

view-budget.component.ts

```
export class ViewBudget implements OnInit {
  ...
  customerMap: any = {};
  ...

  getCustomerName(_id) {
    console.log('ID C:', _id);
    this.customerService.getCustomer(_id).subscribe(data => {
      return this.customerMap[_id] = data;
    })
  }
}
```

view-budget.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let budget of viewbudget; getCustomerName(budget.id)" id="{{budget.id}}">
    <h2>{{ budget.date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</h2>
    <p *ngFor="let customer of customerMap[budget.id]">{{(customer.name)}}</p>
    <p>Fecha Inicio: {{ budget.startdate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="price">$ {{budget.statusid}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this method is not good solution.

you need to handle your backend.

on your backend, you can populate customers using sql join.
so you don't need request to get customers of each budget.